# Using multiple addresses (billing, visitors, delivery) in microdata scheme

Tags: html, microdata

How can I turn the following into a proper microdata scheme:

```
Company logo (imgtag)
Company name
Address: Example street 1, Postcode: 111111, City: Examplecity
Telephone: (+111)555-333-333
Email: person@example.com
BillingAddress: Example street 2, Postcode 22222, City: ExampleCity2
Deliveries: Example street 3, Postcode 33333, City: ExampleCity3
```

When I use LocalBusiness and PostalAdress, I get an error when testing against Google for BillingAddress saying that it's not part of the PostalAddress, and I can only find billingAddress in the Order Scheme, I'm confused.

Comment: You need to include the markup which gives the mentioned errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe **contactType** is what you‘re looking for? http://schema.org/contactType - You can add multiple addresses to an organisation and specify different contactTypes for them...

Google also uses contactType in the examples for adding different service phone numbers, see examples on this page: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/corporate-contacts

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "url": "http://www.your-company-site.com",
  "contactPoint": [
    { "@type": "ContactPoint",
      "telephone": "+1-401-555-1212",
      "contactType": "customer service"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer, From reading the [link](http://schema.org/contactType) you provided, I'm a bit confused as to what `"@type":` I can use in `"contactPoint":`? It doesn't seem to be any standard, or am I wrong here?

Comment: @Elmo the `@type` has always to be `ContactPoint`. If you want to give more information to the type you can add `contactType` with any text, eg `“customer service“`, `“technical support“` or `“bill payment“`. Examples are on this page at the bottom: http://schema.org/ContactPoint